# Why are my two NAS using the router, instead of just the switch?

Tags: networking, router, nas, switch

I have two NAS that are connected to a 1GBIT switch. I used to get only 100MBIT file transfer speeds, which was caused by my router setting the ports to 100MBIT instead of 1GBIT.

So now I am wondering why they had problems with the router?

If they are connected to the same switch, shouldn't they be able to communicate directly with each other?

Comment: The situation is not clear – why would they communicate with each other?

Comment: For transfering files

Comment: But how exactly did you facilitate the transfer? Using a PC and copying/dragging files between the file shares? While copy offloading is (technically) a thing, I very much doubt any NAS would support that across devices.

Comment: I ctrl x the folder on NAS 1, and ctrl v it on NAS 2, using the Dolphin File Manager, on KDE NEON, on a PC, that is connected to the same switch.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you are getting 100Mbits (10Mbytes/s), or are you actually getting 100Mbytes/s? 100Mbytes/s would be what is expected on a 1Gbit connection.

Comment: ok, when you copy/paste like this, the data is all running through the PC, not point to point between the NAS's. if you want point to point, then you will have to login to one of the NASs and perform the copy from within it using whatever software it provides.

Comment: I am absolutely sure that i am getting around 100MBytes now.
But that only happed once i manually changed the port on the router where the switch is connected to GBIT.
Before that i got exactly 11.4MiB/s.
My question is why the the router is involved at all, if the NAS' should be able to do it without the router.

Comment: first, why do you think the router is involved, and second, is the linux PC you are using to perform your transfers connected to the same switch as the NASs, or is it connected to the router, or through the router?

Comment: 1. Because i only got gigabit speed once i changed the port on the router to gigabit.
2. The PC is connected to the same switch

Comment: There are a lot of answers ehere that sound like nonsense especially since the PC was connected to the 1Gbps switch. Can you maybe draw a little diagram and also show the IP address, subnet mask and default gateway of each device (each NAS and your computer), and also show how you copied them? (e.g. drag-and-drop in Windows Explorer and if so, what is the address that is displayed in Windows Explorer?)

Comment: (of course, maybe you're just asking for curiosity's sake and it's not a big problem for you, and adding all this info would be too much work - that's understandable too)

Comment: What happens if you unplug the router for a while?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, if they are connected to the same 1 GBit/s switch, they can talk to each other at 1 GBit/s. However, why would they talk to each other?

You describe you were copying files between file shares. This means your PC will *download* (via the router’s switch, from your description) the files from one NAS and simultaneously *upload* them to the other NAS. The scenic route, so to say. That’s why the router’s switch port being limited to 100 MBit/s matters.

For professional networks, it is sometimes possible that copying is actually performed on the underlying shared storage. This is called [Windows Storage Offloaded Data Transfer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/storage/offloaded-data-transfer) or ODX. At home, the most you can get is copying files on the same file share without them taking the round-trip.

A NAS could also offer some sort of download manager facility that could be used to perform a direct NAS-to-NAS transfer, typically using the NAS’ web interface.

Comment: Thank you very much, then i will just transfer from nas to nas directly.

Comment: The OP wrote in a comment that the PC is connected to the same switch, so the question why the communication involves the router remains, right?

Comment: @CarstenS That’s the OP’s take on the situation. It is, however, impossible—given the reported performance. The communication did not involve the _router_ but only its switch. If that was not the case, it would not have been limited to 100 MBit/s.

Comment: It's not impossible, just unusual for three devices on an L2 switch to require the L3 router in order to communicate with each other.  The router 100Mbit/s port is irrelevant, so this answer is wrong.  Switches are full duplex devices, so "uploading" and "downloading" are irrelevant.  I think Mokubai describes it better, but it still does not make sense.  If the workstation and 2 NAS boxes are on one switched L2 network and a single L3 network, then the router port speed must have zero impact.
My router is 100Mbit/s at the switch, yet I sustain full 1Gbps file transfers easily daily.

Answer (score 4):

This can depend on your networking hardware and the protocols used to transfer the data.

If you have a "layer 2 switch" then it will only operate based on source and destination MAC addresses, a "layer 3" switch functions slightly higher in the network chain and is capable of intelligently routing IP packets.

If you only have a Layer 2 switch and use an IP protocol to transfer files then the routing of packets may be deferred to the router and end up broadcast by the switch on all ports when it gets sent back.

A Layer 3 switch would ignore the router when it has done discovery and found out which IP addresses are on which ports.

From [Layer 2 vs Layer 3 Switch: Which One Do You Need?](https://community.fs.com/blog/layer-2-switch-vs-layer-3-switch-which-one-do-you-need.html)

> A Layer 2 switch works with MAC addresses only and does not care about IP address or any items of higher layers. Layer 3 switch, or multilayer switch, can do all the job of a layer 2 switch and additional static routing and dynamic routing as well. That means, a Layer 3 switch has both MAC address table and IP routing table, and handles intra-VLAN communication and packets routing between different VLANs. **There is also layer 2+ (layer 3 Lite) switch that adds only static routing.** Other than routing packets, layer 3 switches also include functions that require to understand the IP address information of data entering the switch, such as tagging VLAN traffic based on IP address instead of manually configuring a port. Layer 3 switches are increased in power and security as demanded.

Comment: This is not quite correct. As soon as a IP packet reaches it's destination network, all further traffic is directed on L2. A network/broadcast domain at home is for example 192.168.0.0/24 (i.e. 192.168.0.1-255). Assuming the two NASes are on the same network, any traffic flowing between the two should be directly switched between them. If one NAS doesn't know the MAC of the other one, it will use the ARP protocol to discover it on the local network. The accepted answer seems to be far more likely here

Comment: Mokubai is right, as JensV comment assumes certain things about the network.  It would be easy (though unusual) to setup a configuration in which devices on the same L2 switch used the L3 router.

Comment: Can't edit previous comment... Mokubai is right, as JensV comment assumes certain things about the network.  It would be easy (though unusual) to setup a configuration in which devices on the same L2 switch used the L3 router.  It still doesn't answer why the router port is slowing down the other switch ports.  We need a proper description of the network.  My network fits the OP network perfectly, 100Mbit router port on the switch, but I can do server->server copies at full 1Gbps speeds easily.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of what you are talking about, I think, has to do with the switch capabilities.  Yes, the two devices talking to each other on a gigabit switch should be talking directly to each other at full speed, assuming...

- they are set up on the same subnet
- there is no bridging
- the switch doesn't operate in only one mode across the entire switch (either 100Mb OR 1000Mb)

Is this a cheap home/SOHO device?  Most of these aren't capable of reaching the specs they claim.

Comment: They are on the same subnet, there shouldn't be any bridging, the switch has both connections at 1GBIT, the switch is a DGS 1016D

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is your specific switch in combination with an incorrect LAN setting on the router.

In a Gigabit environment all devices should ideally be using auto-negotiate or manually be set to 1 Gb/s full duplex.

But your router was on 100 Mb/s. If the switch doesn't detect that and keeps trying to use Gigabit from his end you get a lot of collisions on the link between switch and router.
(The switch is unmanaged so you can't manually set the link-speed there. It ALWAYS does auto-negotiate. And auto-negotiate is not guaranteed to work in cases were the other side doesn't use auto-negatiate.)

Depending on the switch design, such a link-speed mismatch can lead to the switch throttling traffic (on ALL ports) to reduce the errors. I've seen this behavior happen on a lot of cheap unmanaged SOHO switches, among others also some D-Link models similar to your DGS-1016D.

Comment: Downvote - This is fundamentally wrong on many levels.  Parts are right, but I'm not going to pick it apart bit by bit.  In a switched network there should be no involvement by the router at all, and the speed of the router port should no impact the speed of any other port.  Even the cheapest unmanaged equipment I've ever found still did these basics correctly.